# How to preflight / preview a transaction?

Tags: transactions

Is there a way to preflight/preview a transaction before the actual signAndSend?

I would like to know if a transaction would fail before letting user submit the transaction and prevent user losing gas.

I guess polkadot.js has this kind of function, but nothing find in the doc.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried to make `query` call for the extrinsic? I usually do that if I expect `tx` to fail.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the [`DryRun` RPC method](https://polkadot.js.org/docs/substrate/rpc#dryrunextrinsic-bytes-at-blockhash-applyextrinsicresult) to check the outcome of the transaction.

[Here](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot-scripts/blob/7fd155ce22f3d5702be197544281c2c6a988428b/src/helpers/rpc.ts#L55-L59) is an example:

```typescript
export async function dryRun(api: ApiPromise, signer: KeyringPair, tx: SubmittableExtrinsic<"promise", ISubmittableResult>): Promise<[boolean, ApplyExtrinsicResult]> {
    const signed = await tx.signAsync(signer);
    const dryRun = await api.rpc.system.dryRun(signed.toHex());
    return [dryRun.isOk && dryRun.asOk.isOk, dryRun]
}
```

Note that this RPC is marked as `unsafe`, most public nodes will not expose this and you might need to run your own local node in order to be able to call this.