# How to preview events by dry running an extrinsic?

Tags: api

following this example I can preview if an extrinsic will succeed [How to preflight / preview a transaction?](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/4799/how-to-preflight-preview-a-transaction)

But how can I preview all events emitted by this extrinsic?